# getting to 10 comments of each post using linq to sql method chaining

Tags: c#, sql, linq

To get last 10 comments for each post I do:

```
select * from (
select *,Row_Number() orver(partition by postId order by id desc) RowNum
) where RowNum <= 10
```

Now how do I do exact same thing with Linq method chaining?

**Edit:** The above code is an example, What I exactly want to know is that how partitioning is done with linq.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem about linq or just simply want someone to write it for you?

Comment: I guess you don't read comments...

Comment: well actually I have a problem partitioning I want to know how it is done I just gave this as a sample that you could understand exactly what I mean and I better understand the answer.

Comment: OK, show what you have tried... Otherwise I read it as: *translate this sql to linq for me* which is off topic for SO.

Comment: I don't want a translation, I just want a simple example of partitioning. as I said this was an example just to show you what I mean exactly

Comment: OK I got it. Every lazy  programmer says the same without posting any code showing his effort about the question.

Comment: @EZI you are seriously everything that's wrong with StackOverflow. The guy wants some help doing something he doesn't understand. Instead of being overbearing about it, why don't you help?